# Loading content and images in php from external site that is www.guinnessworldrecords.com/news/rss/

Tags: php

**Loading content and images in  php from external site that is

www.guinnessworldrecords.com/news/rss/**

i am using this :

```
$url="http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/news/rss/";
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$data = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: Please specify your needs, are you loading but there is something wrong, or what? what have you tried, and what are you intending to do?

Comment: i have already written in my question , please ready question again.

Comment: @MoizShafqatHusain Your question has no question-marks in it. You state the feed you're using, and provide a snippet of code that fetches that page via curl. No where do you say what's wrong or what you need help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though the question is hopelessly vague, I'd try answering in the same fashion :

Use AJAX.

Comment: You could either use : jQuery AJAX (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) `load` method or a ready-made AJAX object (http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/The_Ultimate_Ajax_Object)

Comment: Also have you tried a `print_r($data)` to see what you're getting for yourself?